# Setting exact angle between paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, perspective

So I want to draw a line of pseudo-3D boxes with a changing amount of "segments" of constant width (e.g. a box of 3 segments of 60p width, 180p in all, and one of 6 segments of 60p width, 360p in all). The depth of the boxes should be the same, so they align nicely.

Failed example (I want the z-angles of the boxes to be parallel, so I can string up any amount of these boxes in a row without it looking odd):
[image: These boxes should have the same angle, so they look as if they're in a row]

So far, I can only manage something like this, and my attempts to correct the viewing angle distort more than help.

To be honest, I've colored the first 3D-box and copied the others from it to save me the hassle of deleting unused areas and re-coloring each time, so perhaps the answer is "Use independent boxes and adjust the vanishing points manually", but if there's a way to set the angle between to adjacent segments of a path, it would be a lot more comfortable. Does this exist? Alternatively, am I missing an obvious other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding what your problem is? Do you want the two big boxes you are showing to have the same perspective? Wild guess: Try moving a 3D box in 3D-box mode.

Comment: Hey Gecko,, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I think you may be looking for some sort of pseudo-3D feature to calculate vanishing points automatically and allow their adjustment. I don't think that's possible in Inkscape. Illustrator's perspective grids may work.. but that's Illustrator.

Comment: If @Scott is correct then you might want to look at this tutorial for making a perspective grid in Inkscape: http://goinkscape.com/how-to-create-3d-perspective-grids-in-inkscape/

Comment: @Ryan That is pretty cool, and I'd mark it as an answer. My basic idea was to just set the angle manually, using the paths, and some yet-to-be-found-by-me textbox that lets me enter an angle between two path segments.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes, I mentioned it is possible to do box for box, pushing around the vanishing points until it looks sorta right, but this means I have to color each box individually, and do the adjustments. It works (and honestly is quicker than searching for answers online), but it somehow strikes me as a lot of extra work for something so repetetive.

Comment: @GeckoGeorge: The idea behind my guess was that if you move boxes in 3D-box mode, the vanishing points are not affected and thus you should not need to move them around. In particular, result looks entirely different from your example (with the right edges of the left box being almost parallel to the left edges of the right box). But after all I can still only guess what you want your result to look like – can you provide a sketch of some sort, what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z angle of the boxes won't be parallel because the back face is not the same size as the front face. What you are essentially making is a perspective drawing, and parallel lines in perspective don't stay parallel. You can move the endpoints with the edit paths tool. Select all paths using the shift key then click and drag to select the nodes you want. With those nodes selected, click and drag one to move them.
[image: Edit Paths Tool]

You can also go the menu object>transform. Under the rotate tab you can type in values to rotate. If you want to rotate from an endpoint turn on snap to cusp node, then select the path, click the path again to change the transforms to rotate and shear, then move the center of rotation to an end point.
[image: Move Center of Rotation]